# ng-Pattern in AngularJS for exculding just three special characters showing a parsing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Firstly, without the ng-pattern attribute there is no error at all, so it is safe to say that the problem is only in regards to the ng-pattern. I changed the `patternExcludes` variable multiple times, for instance

- `[^\s\$\^]+`
- `/[^\s\$\^]/`
- `/^[^\s\$\^]$/`

and many other variations of these that I can think of.
With the regex being `[^\ \$\^]+` the ng-message is featered correctly but the issues is that in the `Console` in Chrome I get a `Error: $parse:lexerr Lexer Error`. All other variations do not work, some hide/ignore the parsing error.

#### In the Auth Controller

```
patternExcludes = "[^\ \$\^]+";

// pattern automatically is wrapped with '/^' and '$/'
$scope.passwordPattern = patternExcludes;
```

#### In signup.html

```
<input data-ng-model="Password" data-ng-minlength="8" data-ng-maxlength="32" name="Password"
                           type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                           ng-pattern="{{passwordPattern}}" required>
```

#### Also in signup.html

```
<div ng-messages="SignUpForm.Password.$error" ng-if="SignUpForm.Password.$dirty"
                         class="msgColor" role="alert">
                        <!--... omitted ng-messages-->
                        <div ng-message="pattern">Your Password must <strong>NOT</strong> contain special characters</div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the {{}} from around passwordPattern.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern